# on option select show div and hide others

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabs, html-select

I'm working on a part of code with select option value and would like to show specific div on change and hide others. But I can't make it work, here is my code.

I don't understand why the div does not appear in the first example contrary to the second one.

My goal is to have tabs and add select option in tab 1 and divs in tab 2, and when I select an option in tab 1, it shows the result in tab 2 automatically. I hope I was clear.

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  $(".segment-select").Segment();

});


$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".ui-segment span", function() {
    var value = $(this).attr('value');
    $(".box").hide();
    $(".box." + value).show();
  });
  $(".ui-segment span:first").click();
});

(function($) {
  $.fn.extend({
    Segment: function() {
      $(this).each(function() {
        var self = $(this);
        var onchange = self.attr('onchange');
        var wrapper = $("<div>", {
          class: "ui-segment"
        });
        $(this).find("option").each(function() {
          var option = $("<span>", {
            class: 'option',
            onclick: onchange,
            text: $(this).text(),
            value: $(this).val()
          });
          if ($(this).is(":selected")) {
            option.addClass("active");
          }
          wrapper.append(option);
        });
        wrapper.find("span.option").click(function() {
          wrapper.find("span.option").removeClass("active");
          $(this).addClass("active");
          self.val($(this).attr('value'));
        });
        $(this).after(wrapper);
        $(this).hide();
      });
    }

  });

})(jQuery);
```

```css
.ui-segment {
  color: rgb(0, 122, 255);
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 122, 255);
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: 'Lato', Georgia, Serif;
}

.ui-segment span.option.active {
  background-color: rgb(0, 122, 255);
  color: white;
}

.ui-segment span.option {
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-left: 23px;
  padding-right: 23px;
  height: 25px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 25px;
  margin: 0px;
  float: left;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-right: 1px solid rgb(0, 122, 255);
}

.ui-segment span.option:last-child {
  border-right: none;
}

.segment-select {
  display: none;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: helvetica;
}

.tabs input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9999px;
  left: -9999px;
}

.tabs {
  width: 650px;
  float: none;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 75px auto;
}

.tabs li {
  float: left;
}

.tabs label {
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  border-radius: 2px 2px 0 0;
  color: #08C;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-family: 'Lily Script One', helveti;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 3px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.tabs label:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  top: 0;
}

[id^=tab]:checked+label {
  background: #ccc;
  color: white;
  top: 0;
}

[id^=tab]:checked~[id^=tab-content] {
  display: block;
}

.tab-content {
  z-index: 2;
  display: none;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 140%;
  padding-top: 10px;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 53px;
  left: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  -o-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
  animation-duration: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="tabs">
  <li>
    <input type="radio" checked name="tabs" id="tab1">
    <label for="tab1">tab 1</label>
    <div id="tab-content1" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">

      <select class="segment-select">
        <option value="red" selected>Red</option>
        <option value="green">Green</option>
        <option value="blue">Blue</option>
      </select>

    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <input type="radio" name="tabs" id="tab2">
    <label for="tab2">tab 2</label>
    <div id="tab-content2" class="tab-content animated fadeIn">

      <div class="red box">red option</div>
      <div class="green box">green option</div>
      <div class="blue box">blue option</div>

    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @Pete I've seen your second snippet but the problem is that I want to have choices in a tab instead of having them on the tabs

Comment: ok, where is your second snippet @Pete ? because I can test your idea to see result ?

Comment: I worked on it but I refresh my page and lost your snippet, don't worry I understand you and I'm sorry if I was like that to you, it was not my goal, I worked on the same time in several solutions from my side and wanted to show you only things that I approved. sorry again and thanks for your big help Pete

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the DOM, you will find that select box is getting converted to DIV->SPAN structure and show it as tabs. So here normal select box change event will not get triggered.
You need to bind click event on spans and read `value` attribute and then apply logic to show and hide divs.

See below working snippet

```js
jQuery(function ($){

        $(".segment-select").Segment();
          
      });

    
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click",".ui-segment span",function(){
        var value= $(this).attr('value');
        $(".box").hide();
        $(".box." + value).show();
    });
   $(".ui-segment span:first").click();
});



(function( $ ){
    $.fn.extend({
        Segment: function ( ) {
   $(this).each(function (){
    var self = $(this);
    var onchange = self.attr('onchange');
    var wrapper = $("<div>",{class: "ui-segment"});
    $(this).find("option").each(function (){
     var option = $("<span>",{class: 'option',onclick:onchange,text: $(this).text(),value: $(this).val()});
     if ($(this).is(":selected")){
      option.addClass("active");
     }
     wrapper.append(option);
    });
    wrapper.find("span.option").click(function (){
     wrapper.find("span.option").removeClass("active");
     $(this).addClass("active");
     self.val($(this).attr('value'));
    });
    $(this).after(wrapper);
    $(this).hide();
   });
        }

    });
        
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.ui-segment{
 color: rgb(0, 122, 255);
 border: 1px solid rgb(0, 122, 255);
 border-radius: 4px;
 display:inline-block;
 font-family: 'Lato',Georgia, Serif;
}
.ui-segment span.option.active{
 background-color: rgb(0, 122, 255);
 color: white;
}
.ui-segment span.option{
 font-size: 13px;
 padding-left: 23px;
 padding-right: 23px;
 height: 25px;
 text-align:center;
 display:inline-block;
 line-height: 25px;
 margin: 0px;
 float:left;
 cursor:pointer;
 border-right:1px solid rgb(0, 122, 255);
}
.ui-segment span.option:last-child{
 border-right: none;
}
.segment-select{
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>



<h1>EXAMPLE THAT I WANT BUT DOES NOT WORK</h1>
<select class="segment-select">
            <option value="red" selected>Red</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  </select>

      
    <div class="red box">red option</div>
    <div class="green box">green option</div>
    <div class="blue box">blue option</div>  
      
      

<h1>EXAMPLE WHO WORK</h1>
        <select>
            <option value="red" selected>Red</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        </select>

      
    <div class="red box">red option</div>
    <div class="green box">green option</div>
    <div class="blue box">blue option</div> 
      
      
      
      
      
      

<script type="text/javascript" src="segment.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: that's it, the first problem is solved and you are right, if you see my example I update the code few minutes ago and add tabs, how can I go to tab 2 automatically when I select an option ? at this time I can see the result when I click on tab 2, I'm not automatically redirected